Why does SignalR not see current state of data in React app
I have searched many a tutorial and have searched google for hours. I can't find anything to answer why SignalR callback isn't seeing the current state of my data but React does just fine.
First, my code (a simplified version anyways):
React component:
function example() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<DataModel[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadSignalR();
        loadData();
    }, []);

    async function loadData() {
        const serverData= await getAllData();
        setData(serverData);
    }

    function addData(addedItem: DataModel) {
        setData([...data, addedItem]);
    }

    function loadSignalR() {
        signalRService.startConnection(`${BASE_PATH}/dataHub`);
        signalRService.onDataAdded(addData);
    }

    return (
        <div className="ps-3" style={{ minWidth: '50vw' }}>
            <h2 className="w-100 text-center">Data</h2>
            
            <DataCarouselContainer
                data={data}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

and the signalRService:
const signalRService = {
    connection: null,

    startConnection: hubUrl => {
        signalRService.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(hubUrl)
            .build();

        signalRService.connection
            .start()
            .then(() => signalRService.addToGroup('QT'))
            .then(() => {
                console.log('SignalR connection established.');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Error starting SignalR connection:', err);
            });
    },

    onDataAdded: callback => {
        signalRService.connection.on('DataAdded', serverData=> {
            callback(serverData);
        });
    },

    addToGroup: groupName => {
        signalRService.connection.invoke('AddToGroup', groupName).catch(err => {
            console.error('Error adding to group:', err);
        });
    },
};

export default signalRService;

The backend is working fine. It sends events and the front end receives them. Everything seems to work but when addData is called it sees data as an empty array. My screen shows it's not really empty as I can see 4 items listed on the screen.
So what am I doing wrong? Why does SignalR only ever see the state of data as an empty array?
The goodish/terrible news is that in my googling I found a workaround from others with the same issue. If I create a second, throwaway, variable, say:
const [newData, setNewData] = useState<TaskModel[]>([]);

and then add a new useEffect, like:

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([...data, ...newData]);
    }, [newData]);

It works. newData becomes throwaway dataand react sees data as the current state. So in the useEffect I can update the data and have it shown.
Problem is, it's messy and if I want to do more events, like remove data, I need to add more throw away code and more useEffects. It can easily get out of hand and I hate the idea of it. I just want SignalR to correctly see the current status without having to create a new connection every time data changes.
I tried separating the code. I tried setting the data directly, indirectly, and even with an events array.
I tried using a single useEffect to no avail (infinite loop created).
Nothing seems to work expect throwaway code.
